# Como criar um serviço em Python que continue rodando após responder?

Tags: python-3.x

Preciso fazer long-pooling em um site "Principal" para receber eventos.
Depois processo e filtro esses eventos e tenho clientes que fazem long-pooling em mim.
Preciso guardar isso em memória, não da para persistir, e fornecer pros meus clientes.
Independente de não existir clientes ou ter muitos clientes fazendo pooling, preciso sempre fazer um único pooling no site "principal".
Pretendo hospedar isso em um Apache Httpd, mesmo que seja necessário algum módulo especifico.

Comment: Normalmente se fizer esse tipo de coisa com Apache, o usuário estará ocupando uma _thread_ preciosa do servidor durante todo o tempo que roda o _script_, e com poucas requisições o serviço httpd vai estar completamente esgotado, impedindo o acesso por outros usuários.

Answer (score 2):

Acho extremamente improvável que você consiga fazer tal serviço usando Apache. Não conheço como o mod_python funciona, mas se for como qualquer API HTTP, ela é baseada em requisições, e você tem pouco ou nenhum controle sobre a execução do seu contexto em Python, podendo o Apache criar threads, matar e duplicar processos ao seu bel-prazer, e em cada um deles instanciar um contexto Python diferente. A parte que você teria controle é a parte que trata uma única requisição, vinda do seu cliente.

Eu sugiro você fazer um processo "standalone", que rode sozinho, e que ele próprio seja o servidor HTTP. Isso é muito fácil fazer com a biblioteca `gevent`, [por exemplo](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/examples/wsgiserver.py) (embora ela não tenha suporte muito bom a Python 3, a versão para Python 3 não é oficial).

Com o próprio `gevent` você consegue fazer conexão HTTP assíncrona em outros servidores ([gevent.httplib](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.httplib.html)), ou você pode usar essa biblioteca [aqui](https://github.com/gwik/geventhttpclient) para funcionalidades mais avançadas.